# JavaScript: How to reverse letters in each word while maintaining the original order of words, spaces and punctuation?

Tags: javascript

My Apporoach:

```
function wordReverse (str) {

if(str===""){
    return str;
}

punctuationMarksArray = [];
punctuationMarks = /[\-.,;"!_?\\ " "']/g;
punctuationMarksArray = str.match(punctuationMarks);
//now replace punctuation marks with an identifier
str = str.replace(punctuationMarks, "+0+");
//now split the string on the identifier
splitStringArray= str.split("+0+");
//now reverse all words within splitStringArray
splitStringArrayReversed=[];

for(i=0; i<splitStringArray.length; i++){
    reversedString= splitStringArray[i].split("").reverse().join("");
    splitStringArrayReversed.push(reversedString);
}
//now I got two arrays that I need to combine
//punctuationMarksArray and
//splitStringArrayReversed
wynikArray=[];
for(i=0; i<punctuationMarksArray.length; i++){
    wynikArray.push(splitStringArrayReversed[i]);
    wynikArray.push(punctuationMarksArray[i]);
}

return wynikArray.join("");


}
```

For example, `This IS a word-teSt,yo!` should turn into `sihT SI a dorw-tSet,oy!.`
My code does not work on following:

```
wordReverse("You have reached the end of your free-trial membership at www.BenjaminFranklinQuotes.com! -BF");
```

Comment: Aleksander, your question seems to contain spam.  Could you please provide different example text?  Also, please consider moving your example to a [code block or inline code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: More examples are here: https://javascript.onl

Answer (score 1):

You could match only letters and reverse matched groups.

```js
function reverse(string) {
    return string.replace(/[a-z]+/gi, function (s) {
       return s.split('').reverse().join('');
    });
}

console.log(reverse('This IS a word-teSt,yo!'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution assuming you want the string reversed, not just arrange the words backwards

```
function backwards(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}

var text = "Hey this is t3xt!";

console.log(backwards(text));
```